# Can I Compile a Netbeans Platform Application

Tags: netbeans, compilation, platform

I am starting to create A NetBeans Platform CRUD Application and since I will need to run it on different computers I want to know if I can compile it to run as a stand alone app and if there is a way to maybe add an install wizard.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In NetBeans 7.3, it can create Linux, OS X, and Windows installers for a NetBeans Platform Application.

To select which platforms to build installers for:

1. Right-click on your application in the Projects tab
2. Select "Properties" way at the bottom of the list.
3. In the properties dialog that pops up, use the checkboxes in the "Installer" category.

To build the installers:

1. Right-click on your application in the Projects tab.
2. Select "Package as"->"Installers".